# Copy data to and from the same table and change the value of copied data in one column to a specified value in Django

Tags: django, django-queryset

**May be duplication of this one:**
[Copy data to and from the same table and change the value of copied data in one column to a specified value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9225038/copy-data-to-and-from-the-same-table-and-change-the-value-of-copied-data-in-one)

I want to copy the data in a single table and paste in the same table by changing the `owner` coloumn from the given model:

```
class Task(models.Model):

    description = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category)
```

What's the Django way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just reset the `pk` field, update appropriate field and save the object.

```
task = Task.objects.get(id=1)
task.pk = None
task.owner = new_owner
task.save()

#task will create new object/row in the table
```

Comment: Will this not update the same data? What I want is:
`a = Task.objects.filter(user=1)` # Get the data created by admin
Copy all the data from `a` and update `user=request.user.id`

Comment: @user2032220, Have you tried it on shell? No it will create new row as `.pk` is set to `None`.

Comment: Yes, works like a charm. You have assigned `pk` of task instance to `None`. Can you please explain the code. +1 already.

Comment: @user2032220, This doc explains it better than me https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/#how-django-knows-to-update-vs-insert

Comment: `If the object’s primary key attribute is not set, or if it’s set but a record doesn’t exist, Django executes an INSERT.`