# How to Clone all records in a Table while adding a string to name of record and incrementing the record ID

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench, sugarcrm

I created a new Table by Joining 2 other tables together with a specific where clause, this resulted in only 169 records being added to the new table.

What I now need to do is the following

1. Clone all those records to the current table (DUPLICATE)
2. Add a String to current record name
   Example
   Original Record Name: Record 1
   Cloned Record Name: Record 1 - COPY
3. The Records all have unique ID's When cloning, the ID's should be incremented but not be the same as the other ID's of the other records.

NOTE: THE RECORDS IN THIS NEW TABLE IS NOT SEQUENTIAL EXAMPLE BELOW

ID: bf378ee4-2430-264a-e7ec-546e68b12301

ID: bf378ee4-2430-264a-e7ec-546e68b12302

ID: bf378ee4-2430-264a-e7ec-546e68b12303

THIS IS NOT THE CASE

[Copy data to and from the same table and change the value of copied data in one column to a specified value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9225038/copy-data-to-and-from-the-same-table-and-change-the-value-of-copied-data-in-one)

USED TO CREATE NEW TABLE

```
create table sgr_New.tim_time_temp_merged_and_purged as
    SELECT * from sgr_New.tim_time as T
    join sgr_New.tim_time_cstm as C
    on T.id = C.id_c
    where
        (C.billable_time_c > "0")and
        (C.unbillable_time_c > "0")and
        (C.unbillable_reason_c not like "No_Unbillable_Time");
```

Found this online (Is this relevant)
Apologies for the long query I had to specify all the fields as there is one specific field I am not supposed to insert.

```
insert into sgr_new.tim_time_temp_merged_and_purged (c1, c2, ...)
    select 
    unpaid_billable_revenue_c,
    unbilled_hours_c,
    unbillable_time_c,
    unbillable_reason_c,
    training_time_c,
    touched_c,
    total_time_c,
    time_netsuite_id_c,
    time_entered_c,
    tag_c,
    requirements_time_c,
    reporting_time_c,
    related_account_c,
    project_rate_c,
    project_or_case_name_c,
    project_number_c,
    project_mgmt_time_c,
    platform_build_time_c,
    overrun_c,
    num_minutes_c,
    num_hours_c,
    internal_notes_c,
    free_hours_c,
    expense_calculation_c,
    expense_amount_c,
    duration_c,
    dev_time_c,
    date_performed_c,
    data_load_time_c,
    currency_id,
    counter_field_c,
    configuration_time_c,
    category_c,
    case_rate_c,
    case_number_c,
    billing_rate_override_c,
    billing_rate_c,
    billing_notes_c,
    billed_time_c,
    billable_time_wf_copy_c,
    billable_time_override_c,
    billable_time_c,
    billable_override_c,
    billable_hours_kpi_c,
    billable_c,
    billable_amount_c,
    base_rate,
    amount_c,
    account_short_name_c
    from sgr_new.tim.time_cstm
    where id = 1;
```

I expect to see
338 Records in my Table ALL WITH UNIQUE ID's no duplicates
169 of these has "Copy" added to the record name

Comment: INSERT into mytable (id, name, field1, field2, ...) 
  SELECT max(id) + 1, concat('Copy of ', name), field1, field2, ...
  FROM mytable

Think I found my solution

Comment: can you post some of your input and expected output data.

Comment: Found my solution, Thank you for your interest and assistance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a mysql function [`UUID()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_uuid) (in MSSQL: `LOWER(`[`NEWID()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/newid-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)`)` ) that you could call without parameters to generate the IDs in the correct format.

For the name just use `CONCAT()`, but I see you already found it yourself :)

Comment: Yes, I found my solution.
Thanks for your assistance.

Answer (score 0):

INSERT into mytable 
(
id, 
name, 
field1, 
field2,
 ...
) 
SELECT max(id) + 1, concat('Copy of ', name), field1, field2, ... FROM mytable